# How to search for more than one string in VB6?

Tags: string, vb6

I want to search for more than one string in a file  with vb6 
using **instr** we can do it for single string  but I don't know how to use instr for more than one string now how can I search for more than one and if find one of them we receive a message?

```
Open file For Binary As #1
    strData = Space$(FileLen(file))
    Get #1, , strData
Close #1
lngFind = InStr(1, strData, string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simply a case of introducing multiple tests for multiple strings...

```
Dim strArray(10) As String
DIm cntArray(10) As Integer
Dim strData As String
Dim c As Integer

'Set-up your search strings...
...

Open file For Binary As #1
Get #1, , strData
Close #1

For c = 1 to 10
    cntArray(c) = Instr(strData, strArray(c))
Next c
```

If all you want to do is show a true or false message box then we don't need to assign the value to the second array.  The `For` loop could be replaced with...

```vb
For c = 1 to 10
    If Instr(strData, strArray(c)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "'" & strArray(c) & "' found in file."
        'Remove the following line if you want everything to be searched for,
        'but leave it in if you only want the first string found...
        Exit For
    End If
Next c
```

Really this is a very basic piece of code.  If you're looking to write code as anything but a novice then you need to research the commands, functions and structures included in this post.  A good place to start, for a complete novice, would be somewhere like http://www.thevbprogrammer.com/classic_vbtutorials.asp or http://www.vb6.us/.

Comment: PS: You'll have to forgive any syntax problems - my VB6 is pretty rusty!

Comment: TNX BUT CAN YOU DO IT WITH A EXAMPLE? I AM NOOB :d

Comment: Ermm... That's the example code above.  All you have to do is put a list of strings where the `...`s are (e.g. `strArray(1) = "My Little Pony"` etc).  The numbers stored in the `cntArray` is the position of a given string in the list.

Comment: tnx ok so i add this after next c (If c > 0 Then
MsgBox "find:"
Else
MsgBox "not find"
End If) so its fine now? i want to if one of them exist give me a messge

Comment: No - the array `cntArray()` contains the positions of each matching string in the other array, so for example if `strArray(1)` is found in the file string (`strData`) then `cntArray(1)` will reflect the first position that the string was found at (e.g. if `cntArray(1)` = 12345 that means that the string held in `strArray(1)` can be found at the 12345th position in `strData`).  You'll need to check each value to see which one is the most useful to you. You may want to pick the lowest value first for instance, or even the highest - that's down to you!  ;o)

Comment: ok i qutie :D can you change your code? i cant make the msg part i ask some of my vb  friend they cant do that too

Comment: @user3245060: Ok - try what I've posted above, but **please** go away and learn from it, don't just use it as your homework or whatever.

Comment: hi tnx no its not for any kind of that thing. i am trying to learn from source and codes because i not start the vb6 classes yet!wating for summer.any way tnx i try to work on thay

Answer (score 0):

```
'-----------------------------------------------------------
'perform multiple instr on a string. returns true if all instr pass
'-----------------------------------------------------------

Function bMultiInstr(sToInspect As String, ParamArray sArrConditions()) As     Boolean
On Error GoTo err:
Dim i As Integer, iUpp As Integer

iUpp = UBound(sArrConditions) 'instr conditions

For i = 0 To iUpp ' loop them
       If InStr(1, sToInspect, sArrConditions(i)) <= 0 Then Exit Function '     if instr returns 0 then exit - [bPasses] will be left false
Next i

bPasses = True


Exit Function
err:
With err
     If .Number <> 0 Then
        'create .bas named [ErrHandler]  see http://vb6.info/h764u
        ErrHandler.ReportError Date & ": Strings.bMultiInstr." & err.Number     & "." & err.Description
        Resume Next
      End If
End With
End Function
```

That is from http://vb6.info/string/instr-multi-perform-instr-checks-multiple-inst-conditions-function/